# WSO2 ESB: suspended anonymousendpoint

Tags: esb, wso2, wso2-esb

I am working on WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 and facing an issue regarding to suspended anonymous endpoint. The scenario is: TCP/IP transport receiver (custom one) -> Proxy -> invoke HTTP endpoint. 
At the startup runtime, my custom transport receiver will connect to another machine by using TCP/IP protocol and start listener message event. When message event come, the transport receiver will format the message event as JSON format and send it to predefined Proxy (This step is working well even though suspended anonymous endpoint has been occurred). The implement in side the proxy is really simple, just send to HTTP endpoint:

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" />
<property name="Accept" scope="transport" value="application/json" />
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
    <format>$1</format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.eventMessage" />
        </args>
</payloadFactory>
<call>
    <endpoint>
        <http method="post" uri-template="http://localhost:9080/goal"></http>
    </endpoint>
</call>
```

The process is working fine except the  suspended anonymous endpoint has happened (Such as the HTTP endpoint is shutdown), then i am able to see a log message as below:

```
WARN {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext} -  Suspending endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint - current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Tue Oct 28 17:38:23 ICT 2014
```

If i stop the request traffic at the transport receiver and restart the HTTP endpoint, after 30 ms the endpoint can back to service

In case request traffic at the transport receiver still running, i saw the log message above is displayed few times and then the ESB server don't log that message anymore. At this time, the HTTP endpoint is suspended and never come back to service except restarting ESB server

I also saw this log message:

```
WARN {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.TimeoutHandler} -  Expiring message ID : urn:uuid:5dcedb38-3f9a-4a75-a201-ae4e76428216; dropping message after global timeout of : 120 seconds
```

That is really strange for me and i wonder if i did something wrong here. I really need your suggestion guys

Best regards,

An

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a named endpoint and configure suspension and timeout, have a look there : https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Endpoint+Error+Handling

If you don't want to loose any message and if your http endpoint can be down for a long time for exemple, you should consider using guaranteed delivery with message Store and message Processor, have a look there : https://docs.wso2.com/display/IntegrationPatterns/Guaranteed+Delivery

Comment: Hi Michel, thank for reply. Actually i am using connector structure to build template and use the endpoint inside. Any way, i have to build custom mediator to invoke my HTTP endpoint, no suspension  case anymore